# How do I get the SugarCRM Email Dashlet to Update?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, dashlet

I am unable to get my Email dashlet to update. When I run 'repair and build' I get the error messages shown below. I have checked ownership and permission and all are correct. Any advice would be gratefully received. I am a bit of a newbie.

Version 7.2.1
Sugar Version 6.5.20 (Build 1001)

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() occurred in /htdocs/crm/include/externalAPI/ExternalAPIFactory.php on line 109 [2015-05-19 15:21:53] display_stack_trace caller, file: /htdocs/crm/include/utils.php line#: 3254
/htdocs/crm/include/externalAPI/ExternalAPIFactory.php[L:109](:StackTraceErrorHandler)
/htdocs/crm/include/externalAPI/ExternalAPIFactory.php[L:238](ExternalAPIFactory:loadFullAPIList)
/include/externalAPI/ExternalAPIFactory.php[L:277](ExternalAPIFactory:listAPI)
/crm/custom/modules/SugarFeed/Dashlets/SugarFeedDashlet/SugarFeedDashlet.php[L:85](ExternalAPIFactory:getModuleDropDown)
/crm/custom/modules/Home/index.php[L:222](SugarFeedDashlet:SugarFeedDashlet)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php[L:716](:require_once)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/View/views/view.classic.php[L:70](SugarView:includeClassicFile)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php[L:143](ViewClassic:display)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php[L:348](SugarView:process)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php[L:295](SugarController:processView)
/htdocs/crm/include/MVC/SugarApplication.php[L:92](SugarController:execute)
/htdocs/crm/index.php[L:49](SugarApplication:execute)
```

Comment: `APIFactory.php` has a `foreach(...)` on line 109. The value in that foreach has an issue, most likely that it is null or not an array.

Comment: Thank you Tim. This is the code on line 109/110. Does it need to be changed?      foreach($dirList as $dir) {
                if ( $dir == $baseDir.'.' || $dir == $baseDir.'..' || $dir ==

Comment: It's impossible for me to say to be honest. Right now, there's something wrong with `$dirList`, but I don't know enough about this code to advise changing it.

Comment: No problem Tim. If anyone else has any ideas, I would very much appreciate it. Incidentally, the Dashlets works on everything other than emails if that is any help!

Comment: My host managed to assist me is resolving this issue which would appear to have been caused by a missing folder. "Base". Thank you Tim for your advice and suggestion which pointed me in the right direction.